# NServiceBus 2.6 continually retries message when handler throws an exception

Tags: nservicebus

We have a production issue that happens infrequently but when it does it makes the entire service unusable.

The issue is that an exception in a message handler causes NServiceBus to enter an endless loop where it continually retries the message.

I found this post that seems to describe the same issue but I can't find a fix:

http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/4316

Comment: Pretty sure that the issue mentioned in the thread was fixed in 2.6. What exact version of 2.6 are you on?

Comment: It was version 2.6.0.1505. We have now upgraded to a licensed version of 3.2.2. On both versions we run about 20 threads. Our problem is that we need to show that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Is it possible to get an issue id or some other reference where I check whether this is fixed or not?

Comment: Unfortunately we started to use the issue tracker around the 3.0 timeframe:( I'll look at the commits and see what I can find

Comment: That would be great, thanks Andreas :)